# Equivalent of block "from workspace" - Simulink - Sample time series

Tags: matlab, time-series, simulink, resampling

The block "from workspace" from Simulink basically (re)samples a time series when the input is a 2D matrix. I want to perform the exact same operation on a 2D matrix but without using the "from workspace" block. That is, I wanna do the same operation using other blocks. I don't need interpolation to happen.

Here's an example of the operation:

Input (the first column defines the time, the others are the data):

```
[0, 1, 3;
1, 2, 5;
2, 3, 7]
```

Output at time 0:

```
[1;
 3]
```

Output at time 0.5:

```
[1;
 3]
```

Output at time 1:

```
[2;
 5]
```

Output at time 20:

```
[3;
 7]
```

Ref: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html

ps: I don't wanna use the "from workspace" block because it is not code gen friendly.

Best regards,

Comment: Did you look into using the Signal Generator?